# How to flag the most efficient way a column of a dataframe by values of another dataframe's in python/pandas?

Tags: python, performance, select, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe "A" (~500k records). It contains two columns: "fromTimestamp" and "toTimestamp".

I've got a dataframe "B" (~5M records). It has some values and a column named "actualTimestamp".

I want all of my rows in dataframe "B" where the value of "actualTimestamp" is between the values of any "fromTimestamp" and "toTimestamp" pair to be flagged.

I want something similar like this, but much more efficient code:

```
for index, row in A.iterrows():
    cond1 = B['actual_timestamp'] >= row['from_timestamp']
    cond2 = B['actual_timestamp'] <= row['to_timestamp']
    B.ix[cond1 & cond2, 'corrupted_flag'] = True
```

What is the fastest/most efficient way to do this in python/pandas?

**Update:**
Sample data

dataframe A (input):

```
from_timestamp    to_timestamp
3                 4             
6                 9
8                 10
```

dataframe B (input):

```
data    actual_timestamp
a       2
b       3
c       4
d       5
e       8
f       10
g       11
h       12
```

dataframe B (expected output):

```
data    actual_timestamp   corrupted_flag
a       2                  False
b       3                  True
c       4                  True
d       5                  False
e       8                  True
f       10                 True
g       11                 False
h       12                 False
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention that none of the timestamps are unique.

Comment: Is possible remove not `True` values?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I don't see why it helps..
I only need a column, where values are flags what indicate, that this record is corrupted, or not.. So I want to get True/False values for all rows..

Comment: Unfortunately my solution is `5` times slower as iterrows method. :(

Comment: Of course! I've updated the post with sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) package to build an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) from the timestamps in DataFrame A, and then check if each timestamp from DataFrame B is in the tree:

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

tree = IntervalTree.from_tuples(zip(A['from_timestamp'], A['to_timestamp'] + 0.1))
B['corrupted_flag'] = B['actual_timestamp'].map(lambda x: tree.overlaps(x))
```

Note that you need to pad `A['to_timestamp']` slightly, as the upper bound of an interval is not included as part of the interval in the `intervaltree` package (although the lower bound is).

This method improved performance by a little more than a factor of `14` on some sample data I generated (A = 10k rows, B = 100k rows).  The performance boost got bigger the more rows I added.

I've used the `intervaltree` package with `datetime` objects before, so the code above should still work if your timestamps aren't integers like they are in your sample data; you just might need to change how upper bounds are padded.

Comment: Great solution.  Try your timings with `B['corrupted_flag'] = [tree.overlaps(x) for x in B['actual_timestamp']]`

Comment: I actually get slightly better times with `map` compared to a comprehension, which is a little bit surprising, as I generally expect comprehensions to be faster.

Comment: Using your solution I got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in flagCandleDataWithGaps2
  File "C:\DevTools\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2104, in map
    new_values = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1098, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:63192)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 657, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_objects (pandas\lib.c:54610)
MemoryError

Comment: According to your solution I've created a mixed solution, what doesn't throw a MemoryError. My final solution is this:

def flagDataWithGaps(A,B):
    
    A['from_ts'] = A['from'].astype(float)
    A['to_ts'] = A['to'].astype(float)
    A['to_ts'] = A['to_ts']+0.1
    B['actual_ts'] = B['actual'].astype(float)
        
    tree = IntervalTree.from_tuples(zip(A['from_ts'], A['to_ts']))
    col = (tree.overlaps(x) for x in B['actual_ts'])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(col)
    B['is_gap'] = df[0]


Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the ideas above, my final solution is the following (it does not generate MemoryError on big datasets):

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree
import pandas as pd 

def flagDataWithGaps(A,B): 

    A['from_ts'] = A['from'].astype(float) 
    A['to_ts'] = A['to'].astype(float) 
    A['to_ts'] = A['to_ts']+0.1 
    B['actual_ts'] = B['actual'].astype(float) 

    tree = IntervalTree.from_tuples(zip(A['from_ts'], A['to_ts'])) 
    col = (tree.overlaps(x) for x in B['actual_ts']) 

    df = pd.DataFrame(col) 
    B['is_gap'] = df[0]
```