# Numpy/pandas optimization: bins counting

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, optimization, lambda

I would like to "bin" a `numpy.array` or `pandas.Series` `x` by counting the number `N` of values between `begin` and `end`. The result is stored in a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
bins = pd.DataFrame({'from': np.arange(0, 1, 0.01), 'to': np.arange(0, 1, 0.01) + 0.1})
x = np.random.rand(1000000)
bins['N'] = bins.apply(lambda r:  ((x >= r['from']) & (x < r['to'])).sum(), axis=1)
```

When I profile the code, the slowest part of the whole script (which contains many more things) if the last line, especially the lambda: 15 % of the time is spent in that lambda!

I have the feeling the instead of using a `lambda`, I must implemented in a vectorized way, but I can't figure out how.

I'm using Python 3.5, numpy 1.11 and pandas 0.18.1

---

EDIT: Additional information + test with intervaltree

In fact, that binning is used iteratively: the binning is initiated with some data, and might be updated with other data sets.

As suggested, I've tried with intervaltree, but it even get worst in terms of performances. From the second iteration, I received a user arning because the '+' is not supported by numexpr on boold dtype, so it switches to pure python mode.

Comment: Is this a real example? the reason I ask is that normally you could just compare the entire df but your lengths don't match so you can't do that in this case

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. The real world looks like this. In fact, I have millions of data in x, and I'd like to compress them in, let's say, 1000 bins. So, the fact that the lengts don't matches is really expected - that's what ends up with compression (approximative)

Comment: So can you use some kind of histogram like method or `pd.cut`?

Comment: Can you check root's answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37287621/2285236

Comment: Thanks @ayhan. I haven't seen that post ... but it get worst with intervalltree; I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Is this in any way different from creating a histogram? I.e. numpy.histogram(X, [...list_of_edges...]) would not work for you?

Comment: Would the bin boundaries be always at such regular intervals? For example, to solve your sample, you could do : `np.bincount((x*10).astype(int))`.

Comment: @Divakar: Yes: boundaries have fixed width, as `[[min + 0 width, min + 1 width], [min + 1 width, min + 2 width], ..., [max - 1 width, max]]`

Comment: @honza_p Sorry, I didn't knew that ... and that's exaclty what I need: the performances increase is huge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *"...boundaries have fixed width, as [[min + 0 width, min + 1 width], [min + 1 width, min + 2 width], ..., [max - 1 width, max]]..."*, use `numpy.histogram`:

```
bins["N"] = numpy.histogram(x, numpy.concatenate([bins["from"], bins["to"].tail(1)]))[0]
```

It would be simpler than this, but if you have the last edge in bins["to"], you need to include it in the list of bins edges.

For details: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @honza_p. That's exactly what I needed. Sorry, I have completely forgotten np.histogram...

Comment: Not entirely correct yet... Working on the last piece

Comment: It seems to work for me like this: `binsList = np.concatenate([bins['from'].values, [bins['to'].values[-1], ]]); bins['N'] = np.histogram(data, binsList)[0]`

Comment: My last edit should be correct now. Anyway, I wanted to show the direction ;-)

Comment: see my comment, which is not using tail(1), but [-1]. I think it would be more "direct", but I have no clue if it will impact performances...

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the intervals are of regular size could be abused to speed up the code quite a bit. Thus, with the parameters set, you can use [`NumPy's bincount procedure`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), like so -

```
# First off, filter out elements that are outside the min,max limits.
# Then subtract min_val from the filtered elements so that they all start from 0
# Then, scale them w.r.t width and floor them, thus converting them into IDs
IDs = ((x[(x >= min_val) & (x<=max_val)]-min_val)/width).astype(int)

# Finally count those IDs, which is the desired output as new column
bins['N'] = np.bincount(IDs)
```

So, for the posted sample, we would have the params as :

```
min_val = 0
max_val = 1
width = 0.1
```

Sample run -

```
In [156]: # Params
     ...: min_val = 4
     ...: max_val = 8
     ...: width = 0.4
     ...: 
     ...: # Create inputs
     ...: bins = pd.DataFrame({'from': np.arange(4, 8, 0.4), 'to': 
     ...:                                   np.arange(4, 8, 0.4) + 0.4})
     ...: x = 10*np.random.rand(1000)
     ...: 

In [157]: bins['N'] = bins.apply(lambda r:  ((x >= r['from']) & \
     ...:                                      (x < r['to'])).sum(), axis=1)

In [158]: bins
Out[158]: 
   from   to   N
0   4.0  4.4  42
1   4.4  4.8  40
2   4.8  5.2  36
3   5.2  5.6  43
4   5.6  6.0  45
5   6.0  6.4  29
6   6.4  6.8  40
7   6.8  7.2  46
8   7.2  7.6  41
9   7.6  8.0  45

In [159]: IDs = ((x[(x >= min_val) & (x<=max_val)]-min_val)/width).astype(int)

In [160]: np.bincount(IDs)
Out[160]: array([42, 40, 36, 43, 45, 29, 40, 46, 41, 45])
```